# Is it possible to cast a void * to a char **?

Tags: c, pointers, void

I have made this little code:

```
void  *toto = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *) * 8);
char  **tata = (char **)toto;
tata[5][5] = 'a'
```

But I have a *segmentation fault*. How can I convert my `void *` to a `char **` ?

Comment: Why and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's just a test. No reason, no other code.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You're doing it. You're just doing it with uninitialized values, so a crash is the best-case scenario.

Comment: Do you want me to initialize toto and tata with NULL?

Comment: @JérémyPouyet that will crash as well, why dont you use a debugger and see what the values are

Comment: @Jérémy, `char**` - this means that tata is a pointer to a pointer to char. Not two-dimensional array! So, when you typecast toto to it - toto must be a pointer to location, where stored pointer to a char.

Comment: Another example of the confusion caused by the fact that pointers are not arrays.  Or, rather, by the common misconception that they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `malloc` call is allocating space for 64 pointers of *uninitialized* memory. Then, you are using `tata` as a double indirection pointer. That's it:

- `tata` points to the start of the 64 pointers.
- `tata[5]` is the sixth element of the `malloc`d block, and since `tata` has type `char**`, `tata[5]` has type `char*`: a pointer with garbage.
- `tata[5][5]` is the sixth element pointed from the start of `tata[5]`. But since `tata[5]` is garbage, `tata[5][5]` is a random element in your memory space.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is definitely possible. But you'll have to do more.

You have an array of `void`s named `toto`:

```
void *toto = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *) * 8);
```

In other words - `toto` is a pointer to a piece of memory containing `8 * sizeof(char *) * 8` voids - you've probably thought that because computation *suggests* it is an array of pointers, the compiler will figure it itself.
It won't - what a compiler *sees* is something like this:

```
void *toto = malloc(64);
```

therefore you'll end up with a 1-dimensional "flat" array where each element is a `void`.

Now you cast it:

```
char  **tata = (char **)toto;
```

and it's all good so far. Now you have `tata` which points to an array of pointers to char arrays which is **not initialized**. The type of `tata[5]` is `*char`.

So when you do:

```
tata[5][5] = 'a';
```

you're:

1. accessing that array of pointers (`tata`) - ok
2. accessing 6th (indexing from 0) pointer `tata[5]` - ok
3. but `tata[5]` is **not initialized** and contains either NULL or some garbage
4. acessing 6th element of `*tata[5]` - `SEGFAULT`, because it's not valid pointer

What you must do is:

- initialize `toto` to how many "rows" you need in resulting *matrix*
- manually create all those end arrays yourself

So it could look like this:

```
void *toto = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *)); /* assuming 8 rows */
char **tata = (char **)toto;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  tata[i] = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char)); /* assuming 8 columns */
}
tata[5][5] = 'a'; /* all is well now */
```

Which would compile and run without SEGFAULT.

I also suggest doing the cast before malloc and using constants for numbers of rows and columns, which will give us this:

```
int num_rows = 8;
int num_cols = 8;
char **tata = (char**)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
  tata[i] = (char*)malloc(num_cols * sizeof(char));
}
tata[5][5] = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to cast `void *` to any pointer type. Indeed, if it weren't you couldn't use `malloc` to allocate very well, since its return value is of type `void *`.

Of course the area of memory pointed to by the `void *` must still be valid for its use, i.e., large enough and aligned correctly. (In case of `malloc` the returned memory is correctly aligned for “any use”, at least as far a standard C is concerned.)

The bug in your code is here:

```
tata[5][5] = 'a'
```

You are dereferencing the 6th pointer to `char *` counting from the start of `malloc`ed block, which is uninitialised.